# Animator is not playing an AnimatorController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am new to Unity and i'm trying to make the doors. I have problem with this warning "Animator is not playing an AnimatorController" and also my script doesn't work. I am trying to make the doors using Update method instead of OnTriggerStay. I am trying to acces the prefabs Animator to SetBool and SetTrigger but it doesn't work. I found somewhere that maby it's the prefab fault. Maby someone will know the answer on how to acces prefabs animator and make this work?

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject doorsUI;

    public GameObject Doors;

    Animator anim;

    bool isTrigger = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = Doors.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isTrigger == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isTrigger", true);
            anim.SetTrigger("OpenClose");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        isTrigger = true;
        if (other.tag == "Door")
        {
            doorsUI.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        isTrigger = false;
        if (other.tag == "Door")
        {
            doorsUI.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you assign an `AnimatorController` to your `Animator` in the Unity editor?

Comment: Yes, I did this and yet it doesn't work